# kafka-connect-bigquery connector failure

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am utilizing wepay/kakfa-connect-bigquery:2.5.0 and replicating tables using it to BigQuery. Frequently for some topic, an error is encountered while writing to BigQuery and after that the data replication is broken completely.
If I remove the topic from the connector's config, the replication for other tables works.

I am unable to get the topic replicated as whenever I add it back to the configuration, add debug log of `DEBUG ProcessingContext is already in failed state. Ignoring requested operation.` appears and then the connector fails with the following error.

How can I ask kafka-connect-bigquery to reset its processing for the erroring topic and start the replication again?

```
[2023-08-28 08:13:29,103] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=bigquery-loanservice-sink-prod-3-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. Error: A write thread has failed with an unrecoverable error (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: A write thread has failed with an unrecoverable error
Caused by: Failed to write to table
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$maybeThrowEncounteredError$0(KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.java:101)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.maybeThrowEncounteredError(KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.java:100)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.writeSinkRecords(BigQuerySinkTask.java:259)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.put(BigQuerySinkTask.java:321)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:587)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:336)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:237)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:206)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:202)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:257)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: Failed to write to table
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.TableWriter.run(TableWriter.java:106)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException.translateAndThrow(BigQueryException.java:122)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.insertAll(BigQueryImpl.java:1076)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.performWriteRequest(AdaptiveBigQueryWriter.java:96)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.row.BigQueryWriter.writeRows(BigQueryWriter.java:116)
    at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.TableWriter.run(TableWriter.java:93)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:131)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:35)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:128)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:146)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:173)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpContent.writeTo(JsonHttpContent.java:73)
    at com.google.api.client.http.GZipEncoding.encode(GZipEncoding.java:53)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpEncodingStreamingContent.writeTo(HttpEncodingStreamingContent.java:48)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest$DefaultOutputWriter.write(NetHttpRequest.java:76)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.writeContentToOutputStream(NetHttpRequest.java:174)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:117)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:514)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:455)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.insertAll(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:492)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$28.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1068)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$28.call(BigQueryImpl.java:1065)
    at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.insertAll(BigQueryImpl.java:1064)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

> reset its processing for the erroring topic

I'd recommend looking at your `errors.tolerance` setting first.

Otherwise, you can use `kafka-consumer-groups` command to seek forward the offsets for a particular topic in the sink connector group

By the way, the latest version of the connector is 2.5.2, so maybe an upgrade has fixed this issue

Comment: `error.tolerance` is already set to "all" and the DLQ has already been set. I will try upgrading the connector and reply back.

Comment: Upgrading the connect to 2.5.2 also didn't help. The odd part about the error is that it just prints and `IllegalArgumentException` and does not even mention the table for which the issue is occuring.

Comment: You can check the source code / report issues at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery/ But `Preconditions.checkArgument` seems to be throwing an error with your data. Are you sending JSON, or something else like Avro for the failing topic? Are there any null values / tombstone records?

Comment: The messages are directly being sourced from Debezium for PostgreSQL, I suppose expecting direct compatibility was a mistake. The data is from Debezium so tombstone events must be there. Have you earlier faced any similar issue with Debezium + kcbq combination?

Comment: In general, there's never guaranteed compatibility between different connector projects, but that's a general issue with ETL processes... Debezium doesn't always have tombstone. You can turn those off, then you get data with `"op":"d"` fields